# Opening a new DB with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to open another db using VBA from my current db then close the one I am in. When I use the code listed here it opens Access but closes it immediately. I am sure it is simply something I am overlooking but the past hour I have wracked my brain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Command115_Click()
Dim objAccess As Access.Application

Const conPATH = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

'Create an instance of the Access application object.
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

'Open the database
objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase conPATH

'Open the form.
objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "Main-Form"

' Maximize other Access window
objAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter

Comment: Try adding your Access object to a public collection in a module?

Comment: I placed the code in a module as a Public Function then called it with the same result. Is that what you meant for me to do or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the shell then when you close your first database, the second will remain open.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Variant
    sh = Shell("""C:\...\MSACCESS.EXE"" ""C:\...\FileName.accdb""")
End Sub
```

My guess the reason your code didn't work is because, the second access you start is an object that exists within the first one.  The moment the first one closes and cleanup starts for its objects/variables.  It closes the second one.

Comment: This is a link for command line switches for access.  You may find them useful when you open accdb/mdbs.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/command-line-switches-for-access-HA010166605.aspx

Comment: Perfect! Just added vbMaximized focus and a close for this one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Say your first app is access1 and it is trying to open access2 and then close access1 app and makes access2 as active app. One thing you could do is, 
Once your access1 app loads try to open access2 app programatically and make it visible and then use Application.closeCurrentdatabase to close access1 database and then in the unload event of access1 apps form (if there is any form in access1 app) call Application.Quit.

This works.